# Map visualization library with scrolling

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial

I'm trying to build an app that displays a map that can zoom to different parts of the globe and display animated data based on live streaming data. I'm fairly new to geospatial visualization, and every visualization library I've been able to find only allows animated data on top of a static map. Some like Folium seem to allow zooming in and out but not moving the location.

I'm looking for recommendations for a python library/framework that can do this. I'm using python because that's what I know, but if there's another language that does this much better I would accept those suggestions as well. The map does not have to be interactive at this point, although keeping that option open would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

**Folium** seems to be the right option.
It is easy to include in python and allows zoooming

See nice guide [here](https://realpython.com/python-folium-web-maps-from-data/)